# Using Windows azure local storage space for temporary file processing

Tags: azure, resources, local

We are using azure local storage for processing temporary files. These temporary files would be uploaded to the local storage through application.
For that I have configured the following code in ServiceDefinition.csdef file.

**local resources
LocalStorage name="ELearningSpace" sizeInMB="2000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="true"
Local resources**

We have used the following code to access the local storage of azure instance 
**LocalResource uploadFolder = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("mylocalStore");
file.SaveAs(uploadFolder.RootPath + "Content/" + collection["packageType"].ToString() + "/" + fileName);**
Also included the dll(made the dll copy local true)

- Microsoft.identity.model.
- Microsoft.Windowsazure.serviceruntime.

Problem:
In my local machine with cloud stimulator the above mentioned code is working fine. But in the actual cloud environment I am getting an error. 
**Exception:
"The type initializer for '' threw an exception."
"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException Message: Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Source: mscorlib ?**

Some one please help me to find where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are scenarios where **Copy Local=true** isn't sufficient ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benko/archive/2012/04/07/cloud-tip-9-add-microsoft-identitymodel-to-the-gac-with-a-startup-task.aspx)). Try installing the WIF Runtime instead using the [Azure Plugin Library](https://github.com/richorama/AzurePluginLibrary/tree/master/plugins/WIF) or the [Windows Azure Bootstrapper](http://bootstrap.codeplex.com/). Installing the runtime will also copy the assemblies to the GAC and this should solve your issue.